# MicroService or Connecting to two databases?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Is it good to connect to two database from Spring boot properties or having separate two war or jar files connect to two different databases, similar to Microservice ?

Answer (score 0):

One of best practices in MS architecture is single persistent database each micro-service.

If you need two databases, you need to check maybe you try to combine two micro-services in one.

I attach good diagram.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be a problem. It depends among other things on quantity of code using each database. If you have 50 classes using database A and another 50 using database B, then maybe you want to divide your application to 2 separate applications. But if you use database A mainly and database B just with one service or something like that, then it is fine.

There is no rule that says that you have to have separate microservice for each database. You have to decide yourself or with your team if it is worth to have multiple microservices, because it comes with another challenges.